# Issue with results after upgrading elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am upgrading my elasticsearch from 2.2 to 7.1 and I am maintaining both the instances and I am trying to compare the results on the new version and old version by making the same search queries.

Note: I have not changed the mappings, settings or querying logic

My results are almost the same but vary a little in scoring. Is it expected? though the documents, mappings, settings and query logic are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch 2.x version uses the [tf/id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)f for scoring and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html) ES doc explains it in details.

While ES 7.X uses the improved [BM25](https://speakerdeck.com/elastic/improved-text-scoring-with-bm25) algorithm for score calculation. [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables) is another nice article from ES which explains it in details.

In short yes, there are significant changes in the scoring formula of ES 2.X and 7.X as underlying algorithm changed itself and even though you have everything else same like documents, mappings, settings and query, still you will be having a different score.

You can use the [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) API on your query to understand the score of documents returned by the query.